# What does cluster size mean (in context of k-means)?

Tags: k-means

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

It states that: `K-means separates data into Voronoi-cells, which assumes equal-sized clusters (not adequate here)` and shows the image:

[image]

Question: What do they *mean* by *size*? Is it the *size of the spread* of the cluster or the *amount of points* in the cluster?

Comment: Two other related questions 
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179297/assumption-of-equal-size-of-clusters-in-clustering
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326685/is-it-true-that-k-means-has-an-assumption-each-cluster-has-a-roughly-equal-numb?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

The *area* of the original (occupied) data space, and to a lesser extend the area of the clusters convex hull, volume, spread. Not the cardinality.

Counterexample in 1 dimension, k=2: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100. Both kmeans clusters will cover a "similar" *area* of the data range (out of 1..100, values in 1..52.75 will be assigned to cluster 1, 52.75..100 will be cluster 2, but the cardinalities are 10 to 1). Note that the "spread" isn't always that similar: the last cluster has spread zero. But you could also use 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10 as example. But this is just a rule of thumb, not a guarantee.

Remember that kmeans tries to minimize the SSQ. **You usually do not improve SSQ by more evenly distributing the points**, but the minimum SSQ will *usually* benefit from **minimizing the SSQ of each part *even* if that means making the cardinalities different**.